# How to publish web service on internet

Tags: web-services

I have written a web service and deployed in Apache Tomcat in localhost:8080.
It works perfectly on localhost:8080.

I just need to know how to make it available to others over internet (not only localhost) just like the webservice written for temperature convert in w3schools website. I can access that anywhere if I am connected to internet.

Comment: have u search on google??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use Amazon's EC2 Service for hosting a webservice..

Comment: Successfuly used Amazon EC2 service. Thanks a ton for suggesting me at the right time !!

Comment: Apologies for the downvote, but I don't think this answers the question above (other than "use a hosting company"). The question is of low quality, and my advice is generally to not answer these, or to just answer in the comments. It escaped being put on hold last year, I am trying again.